# Filehelpers: Class containing Dictionary to csv

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am trying to export csv file using FileHelpers engine.
The class has Dictionary property. Each dictionary key should be separate column in a csv file

e.g.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Props { get; init; }

}
```

| Id | Name | Prop1 | Prop2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | Val 1.1 | Val 1.2 |
| 2 | John | Val 2.1 | Val 2.2 |

`Props` count may vary from  case to case, but there will be same number of dictionary entries for each particular case so it is easy to make columns.

running the simple code

```
var records = new[]
{
    new Customer(1, "James", new()
    {
        { "Property1", "PropertyValueForJames" },
        { "Property2", "PropertyValueForJames" }
    }),
    new Customer(1, "John", new()
    {       
        { "Property1", "PropertyValueForJohn1" },
        { "Property2", "PropertyValueForJohn2" }
    }),
};

var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Customer>();
engine.WriteFile(@"c:\temp\Output.Txt", records);
```

results in exception

```
FileHelpers.BadUsageException: 'The field: 'Props' has the type: Dictionary`2 which is not a system type, so this field needs a CustomConverter (please check the docs for more info).'
```

I tried to google the solution but seems there is not much on this topic. Just curious if there is a straight forward / or best practice on how to do this?
May be some `dynamic`  options.

Comment: Did you [consult the documentation](https://www.filehelpers.net/example/Converters/CustomConverter/)?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in the exception message? _"... so this field needs a CustomConverter (please check the docs for more info)."_

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes i did, but there is nothing on how to convert array into set of fields. I can get object on input, alright, but how to produce several columns from converter is not stated (or i have not found).

Comment: I don't think FileHelpers supports 1-to-many mappings like that - it's 1 class member = at most 1 cell/string in the CSV. You might wanna check out [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper) instead

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen I can do ExpandoObjects with CsvHelper which solves my issue, still leaving all care about quotes and delimiters on the library.